# How to pull a docker image and execute it from github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

How does one pull an image from a github action. Specifically one that requires authentication:

```
    steps:
      - name: Pull Docker Image
        uses: docker/???
        image: image_host.com/image:latest
```

^^^ Is wrong and I am not sure what the right syntax is.

I want to then run a command inside of the action

````
      - name: Run test
        run: |
          node index.js # (index.js is inside of the container)
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a GitHub workflow with a Docker container, you need a workflow runner which has Docker installed on its system, such as [ubuntu-latest](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md). Then use the [*container* directive](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container) in order to pick a container.